# Is there any option to let my article section be more matched?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying make my first wordpress theme.
Now i work in article section on my home page.
I have some logical problem with my article layouts.

That's my actual layout.

```css
/* Article Section */
div.middle-container { 
    width: 100%;
}

/* Left Banner Section */
div.banner-conteiner {
    width:25%;
    height:100px;   
    float:left;     
}

/* Article Container */
div.article-container {
    float:left;
    width:75%;      
}

/* Content Area */
article.post {
    max-width:330px;
    background: white; /* DO ZMIANY !! */
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 4%;
    border-radius: 12px 12px 24px 24px;
    box-shadow: 0 15px 35px rgba(50, 50, 90, .1), 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .07);
    transition: .6s ease;
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

JUST EXAMPLE OF ART :)

```css
               HEADER
______________________________________
|         | |    P     |  |     P    |    
|    B    | |    O     |  |     O    |
|    A    | |    S     |  |     S    |
|    N    | |    T     |  |     T    |
|    N    | |          |  
|    E    | |          |  |    P     |
|    R    |               |    O     |
|         |               |    S     |
|         |               |    T     |
|         |
|         | |    P     |  |    P     |
|         | |    O     |  |    O     |
|         | |    S     |  |    S     |
|         | |    T     |  |    T     |
______________________________________
              FOOTER
```

I want let this articles flow when i add new post, but when one is too long it's stuck because of previous article and leaves too much free space. Is there any option for something like that?

Also maybe you know, is there any option to display only +/- 6 newest posts in my home page?

Comment: It's not possible to fix it with CSS, the only option how to fix it with CSS is to make all  posts height same. BUT if you want to have posts with different heights, you can do it with JS, simply create 2 columns and with some JS code you will be filling it with posts.

Comment: If my answer was the solution for your question, please select it as correct answer with the checkmark icon next to the up/down vote arrows :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is often an issue when using floats. You can try clearing every other post on the left side, so that they don't get stuck after posts taller than others.

For example:

```css
.post:nth-of-type(2n+2) {
    clear: left;
}
```

...which might give you something like this:

```
               HEADER
______________________________________
|         | |    P     |  |     P    |    
|    B    | |    O     |  |     O    |
|    A    | |    S     |  |     S    |
|    N    | |    T     |  |     T    |
|    N    | |          |  
|    E    | |          |
|    R    |             
|         | |    P     |  |     P    |
|         | |    O     |  |     O    |
|         | |    S     |  |     S    |
|         | |    T     |  |     T    |
______________________________________
              FOOTER
```

Still some extra space, and this will only work as long as there are two posts in every row. It is perhaps not an optimal solution when you want to scale things to smaller viewports.

If you want something more robust, you could try removing all your floats and use a [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) combination instead:

```css
/* Example without any spacing or other styling */
.middle-container {
    display: flex;
}

.banner-container {
    flex: 25%;
}

.article-container {
    flex: 75%;

    /* Grid with two columns */
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

This will basically give you the same visual result as the float version, but with a lot more tools to adjust for different viewports, post alignment etc.

If you want a true [masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com) layout I suggest using a third-party JavaScript like @Tmba suggests. There are lots of alternatives.